# Java error: not a statement with charsequence variable

Tags: java

I have a simple code in java using charseqquence:

```
static class baloon {
    CharSequence Titles[];

          public baloon(String lastlevel) {
          if(lastlevel.equals("No"))
                   {
                      Titles[] = {"What to See", "Gallery", "Getting there", "Need to Know", "Description"};
                   }
            else {
                       Titles[] = {"Description", "Gallery", "Getting there", "Need to Know"};
                 }

}
```

At Titles[] = {....... it shows `Java error: not a statement`

Comment: remove the [] from that statement

Comment: then it shows illegal start of expression and also in the android studio it shows array initializer is not allowed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Titles[] = {"What to See", "Gallery", "Getting there", "Need to Know", "Description"};
```

to

```
Titles = new CharSequence[] {"What to See", "Gallery", "Getting there", 
              "Need to Know", "Description"};
```

Comment: why using CharSequence instead of String?

Comment: but how to know that we have to add new charsequence[].

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi that's just the way it works in Java *(if you want to separate the declaration from the initialization)*. But if you were declaring & initializing the array in the same statement, `CharSequence[] Titles = {"What to See", "Gallery", 
                "Getting there", "Need to Know", "Description"};` would have been valid.